# Selling most appreciated units or least appreciated

Tags: united-states, stocks, selling

I have been consistently receiving RSUs. Now i want to steadily sell them to reduce my exposure and diversify.Should i be selling the least appreciated unints or most appreciated? Is there any strategy around it? My belief is that the stock will remain steady for next 1-2 years

The stock is at all time high, so i cant loss harvest (as of today)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to minimize your tax impact for a certain number of shares sold, selling the least appreciated units would accomplish that. However, if you wanted to harvest gains (for example, maybe you expect 2024 to be an unusually low-income year), then selling more appreciated stock could be the right move. The same considerations apply to deciding whether to sell the short-term or long-term gain stock first. Ultimately, it will depend on your specific situation and what you want to accomplish over time.